# Is SOAP the only Service related Implementation of OPC UA and how does it compare to Rest?

Tags: rest, web-services, soap, swagger, opc-ua

I have Problems understanding best practice around OPC UA.
OPC UA is often called Protocol of future IOT and other positive stuff.
In my understanding, if you want to Provide Information over OPC UA as a Service you Implement SOAP Web services. As far as my Knowledge goes, RESTful services are just better in most Use cases.

I know SOAP  REST comparisons that call Rest the better choice and then there are some Industrial Adverts calling OPC UA better then REST …

Pro Rest:
https://spf13.com/post/soap-vs-rest/

Pro OPC UA:
https://www.maintworld.com/Partner-Articles/Why-use-OPC-UA-instead-of-a-RESTful-interface

In my Conclusion, unless there are other Implementations of OPC UA then SOAP. REST seems without hesitation better.

Am I wrong in the Understanding that SOAP is the common Implementation of OPC UA?
Are not most Features of this “Amazing” Protocol behind RESTful standards? 
How Comes most Production Related Software Products focus on OPC UA instead of REST?

Thanks for any Advice or Source of Information!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In my understanding, if you want to Provide Information over OPC UA as a Service you Implement SOAP Web services.

Not even close.

> Am I wrong in the Understanding that SOAP is the common Implementation of OPC UA?

Yes, very.

The term “SOAP” literally isn’t used in the OPC UA article you linked to. I think you need to go back to step zero and start reading some introductory OPC UA material.

---

Here’s an overview article that even touches on the fact that there used to be an optional SOAP/HTTP transport defined by the spec, which may be the source of some of your confusion: https://www.rtautomation.com/technologies/opcua/

Newer versions of the spec have deprecated this transport because almost nobody used it. The UA TCP binary transport remains the only transport required to be implemented and the overwhelmingly most commonly used.

Comment: Thanks that already helped.
Still have Problems for why I should use OPC UA compared to a polished REST environment in most Use Cases. However, before I submit another question, I will spend more research and if I ask something, I will link it here.

Comment: The main difference between REST and UA TCP is that UA TCP is optimised binary and therefore much faster.

Comment: @PaulPascher read about OPC UA’s data model. You seem to be stuck thinking at the “transport” layer about protocol and service calls and there’s so much more than that offered by OPC UA.